# Kotlin runBlocking and async with return

Tags: kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

I am taking my first steps in kotlin coroutines and I have a problem.

In order to create `Foo` and return it from a function I need to call two heavy service methods asynchronously to get some values for `Foo` creating. This is my code:

```
   return runBlocking {
        val xAsync = async {
            service.calculateX()
        }
        val yAsync = async {
            service.calculateY()
        }
        Foo(xAsync.await(), yAsync.await())
    };
```

However, after reading logs is seems to me that `calculateX()` and `calculateY()` are called synchronously. Is my code correct?

Answer (score 4):

Your code isn't perfect, but it is correct in terms of making `calculateX()` and `calculateY()` run concurrently. However, since it launches this concurrent work on the `runBlocking` dispatcher which is single-threaded, and since your heavyweight operations are blocking instead of suspending, they will not be parallelized.

The first observation to make is that blocking operations cannot gain anything from coroutines compared to the old-school approach with Java executors, apart from a bit simpler API.

The second observation is that you can at least make them run in parallel, each blocking its own thread, by using the IO dispatcher:

```
return runBlocking {
    val xAsync = async(Dispatchers.IO) {
        service.calculateX()
    }
    val yAsync = async(Dispatchers.IO) {
        service.calculateY()
    }
    Foo(xAsync.await(), yAsync.await())
};
```

Compared to using the `java.util.concurrent` APIs, here you benefit from the library's IO dispatcher instead of having to create your own thread pool.